# Why do Last Seen in my Pro Webmasters profile page is not updating properly?

Tags: support, profile-page

In my Pro Webmasters profile page, Last seen is not updating properly. I have this problem for a long time. Who do it's not updating even I visit my page so often? Is this a bug which is common for all SE sites or only with Pro Webmasters?

See the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page is cached for a while.

Once the cache expires, the value will change.

Comment: Can you please give an estimate of *a while*?

Comment: It is 2 minutes server side, but it might be cached by proxies and the browser as well (which we can't control).